# Format date picker

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

I have a date picker in my application scene and would like to format it.

So far I was able to adjust the font size of the date picker.

DatePicker.css:

```
.datepicker {
    -fx-font-size: 12px
}
```

How for example can I change the border of the today date or the background of the hovered date? I tried `.datepicker:hover`, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You perhaps have to provide us with the HTML code of your date picker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074459/javafx-2-and-css-pseudo-classes-setting-hover-attributes-in-setstyle-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *almost* works:

```
.date-cell:hover {
  -fx-background-color: yellow ;
  /* etc */
}
```

I say "almost" because it doesn't work the first time the date picker's popup is shown, only on subsequent showings. That's a bug, which you should file at https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

I can't figure a workaround off the top of my head, but will try later...

You can format the cell showing the selected date with

```
.date-cell:focused {
  /* ... */
}
```

and the field showing the selected date with

```
.date-picker .text-field {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually works great in my application, even the first time I "open" the date picker calendar window. Can I also format the today field using this method?

Comment: See update. I assume by "today field" you mean either the text field showing the selected value, or the cell corresponding to the same

Comment: `.date-cell:focused` that's the one i was looking for. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to achieve this by directly using style's on the `datepicker` and I am not sure whether you have access to `datecell` directly via `css`, but it must exist !

So you can try something like this,

```
.date-cell:hover{
        //your style
 }
```

**Hint** : You can look in `modena.css` of `javafx8` for it.

Consider it as a hack, you can override the **Day Cell Factory** of date picker

```
final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = 
        new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (//day is today) {
                             setStyle(" -fx-border-color:black, 
                                              -fx-border-style:solid,
                                                          -fx-border-width:1px");
                        }   
                 }
          };
    }
};
checkOutDatePicker.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);
```

A complete example can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHEBIFF)

Comment: Thank you. This looks somewhat more complicated than what I was thinking. However, I will give it a try. Thanks!